# i'm trying to get all my media query attachments via ajax in wordpress

Tags: ajax, query, attachments, backbone

i'm trying to load all my media files via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
type: 'post',
data: {
    'action':                   'query-attachments',
    'post_id':                  0,
    'query[orderby]':           'date',
    'query[order]':             'DESC',
    'query[posts_per_page]':    -1,
    'query[paged]':             1
},
});
```

as you can see i'm trying to get ALL my media files:

```
'query[posts_per_page]':    -1,
```

in my template, i'm trying to get and display all this images from AJAX 'data':

```
<% if(this.data.length > 0){ %>
    <% for(var i=0; i<this.data.length; i++){ %>
        <img src="<%= this.data[i].sizes.thumbnail.url %>" />
    <% } %>
<% } %>
```

and see this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

but if i change query[posts_per_page] to 39, like this:

```
'query[posts_per_page]':    39,
```

it works fine, where is the problem? trying to solve this problem for 2 days, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have an image that was smaller or equal to the thumbnail size, if so, then no thumbnail will be created, and this.data[i].sizes.thumbnail will be undefined.

Comment: How do you mean no?! You can't depend on `sizes.thumbnail` on being defined - or indeed `sizes`. Change your template to eg `<img src="<%= this.data[i].sizes && this.data[i].sizes.thumbnail ? this.data[i].sizes.thumbnail.url : this.data[i].url %>" />`

Comment: @bonger I have no words to thank you very much! this is amazing.